# Blazor asp.net core hosted app doesnt register partial class to its razor component

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I was trying to transform my client only WASM to asp.net core hosted, however, my component.razor doesn't register it's component.razor.cs partial class anymore.

Auth.razor

```
    <Warning Display="@_display" Message="@WarningMessage"/>
    @{
        if (Properties == null)
        {
            <p><em>Loading...</em></p>
        }
        else
        {
            foreach (var prop in Properties)
            {
                <InputBox @bind-InputValue="prop.Value" Name="@prop.Name" IsPassword="@prop.IsPassword"/>
            }
        }
    }
    <button type="submit" @onclick="@SubmitButton_Click">Submit</button>
</div>
```

Auth.razor.cs

```
namespace Project.Pages
    }
    public partial class Auth
        {
            private IEnumerable<InputField> Properties { get; set; }
            .
            .
            .
        }
    }
```

When I open the project in Rider it even stacks.
If you need any ideas or explain to me the difference between this and creating a base class

Comment: It's quite easy to get a code-behind file wrong as you've seen. The simplest approach is start with a combined HTML + code `.razor` file - then _right-click_  the `@code` statement: there should be a refactoring short cut to convert to a code-behind file.

Comment: @Quango Thank you I didn't know about this feature... I just started using Blazor recently and it's still kind of messy.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Namespace was supposed to be `Project.Client.Pages` since the server part also contains Pages.

Comment: You can also specify the Namespace for the Razor file `@namespace Project.Pages`, which is common in larger projects and removes the directory structure dependence.